# using Linq in Razor view produces runtime error

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

causes a runtime error
[image]

i have this in my web config

```
<add namespace="System.Linq" />
```

and have also tried the @using System.Linq but always get this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats is the type of the Model?

Comment: your `TutorialsEntity` must not be `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Jonesopolis - I'm such an idiot!!!! Is there a Linq extension to check if a model is empty? can't seem to find one?

Comment: `LINQ` is a bunch of extensions over `IEnumerable` types, so no.  But you need to define what you mean by your model being empty, if it's not a collection.  E.g. how would you check if a `DateTime` is empty?

Comment: I see your point. The issue I was having is that there could have been a situation where the return value could just have been a new instance of a Tutorials Entity with no data (Empty as I put it). If this happened I wanted it to do something different . I've changed it to return null now though.
Cheers for the help